# Check whether a string value present in Set using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
public class Role implements Serializable {

/** other fields */


    private Set<Privilege> privileges;


    /* setters and getters */

}
```

//privilege class

```
public class Privilege implements Serializable {


@Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    private String name;

}
```

Having Roles Data with me;

```
Set<Role> roles = SecuUtil.getUser().getRoles();
```

How can I check In privilege does it contain name="test" and return true or false

How can I do it using stream in Java 8, most efficiently

How can we search a set inside set.

For one set I can do like this

```
roles.stream().anyMatch(str -> str.getPrivileges().equals("test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have deciphered your question correctly, you have a user with a set of roles, and you want to check if the set contains any role that contains a privilege with name `"test"`.

If that is what you want, you could do it by flatmapping the roles/privileges into a stream of privileges.

```
if (roles.stream()
     .flatMap(role -> role.getPrivileges().stream())
     .anyMatch(pr -> "test".equals(pr.getName()))) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This is "efficient" insofar as it will stop as soon as it finds one matching privilege.

Comment: What possible exception can throw by this ?

Comment: If any of your variables is null, you could get a `NullPointerException`.